# Formatting WQL Query in powershell

Tags: sql, powershell, wmi, wql

I'm trying to format a WQL Query in powershell to look only for the Wired Ethernet adapter by using the following code

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter "Name LIKE '%Ethernet%' OR '%Gigabit%'" -CN "." | Out-Host
```

However I dont have much knowledge of SQL/WQL and im not sure if im formatting the OR statement correctly in PS if someone could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the documentation on [WQL operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394605.aspx) and [the WQL WHERE clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394054(v=vs.85).aspx)

Based on the documentation, your method is correct, but your syntax was off.  If you are on PSv3+, I'd suggest using the CIM cmdlets as the WMI ones are technically deprecated.

```
Get-CimInstance -Query 'SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration WHERE Name LIKE "%ethernet%" OR Name LIKE "%gigabit%"'
```

In your example:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class 'Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration' -Filter 'Name LIKE "%ethernet%" OR Name LIKE "%gigabit%"' -ComputerName '.'
```

---

Additionally, @Avshalom is correct in that your field is wrong.  You want to be looking at the 'Description'.

```
Get-WmiObject -Filter 'Description LIKE "%ethernet%" OR Description LIKE "%gigabit%"' -Class 'Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration' -ComputerName '.'
```

Comment: Thanks! I've got it sorted now

Answer (score 0):

`Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration` has no `Name` Property.

Anyway regarding your question you can use the filter this way, in the example i'm using valid property like `ServiceName`

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter "ServiceName like '%msloop%' or ServiceName like '%tunnel%'"
```

Also, you don't have to Provide a `ComputerName` Parameter for the local computer, it's the default